# Integer Worksheet in Google Sheets with App Script randomizing numbers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, math

I want to create a worksheet for adding/subtracting integers.  When I run the script I would like the integers to randomly repopulate in two different columns along with the operation(addition/subtraction) in a middle column. Help please :)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help please show what you have tried and add brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### 24 Lines of Problems

```
function operatorsandintegers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const ops = ["-","+","*","/"];
  sh.clearContents();
  let vs = [...Array.from(new Array(24).keys(),x => [Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),ops[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),''])];
  vs.unshift(["Operand1","Operation","Operand2","result"]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

| Operand1 | Operation | Operand2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 74 |  |
| 17 | / | 66 |  |
| 14 | + | 89 |  |
| 76 | + | 2 |  |
| 72 | / | 27 |  |
| 42 | + | 85 |  |
| 34 | * | 62 |  |
| 50 | + | 80 |  |
| 33 | - | 40 |  |
| 61 | * | 34 |  |
| 30 | / | 66 |  |
| 98 | / | 69 |  |
| 27 | - | 26 |  |
| 74 | - | 15 |  |
| 44 | * | 14 |  |
| 66 | - | 42 |  |
| 43 | / | 64 |  |
| 96 | - | 83 |  |
| 52 | - | 29 |  |
| 17 | + | 77 |  |
| 30 | + | 34 |  |
| 31 | / | 31 |  |
| 26 | + | 67 |  |
| 53 | + | 68 |  |

#### Correct answers

```
function correctanswers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const ops = ["-","+","*","/"];
  let r = vs.map(r => {
    let idx = ops.indexOf(r[1]);
    if(~idx) {
      switch(idx) {
        case 0:
          return [r[0] - r[2]];
          break;
        case 1:
          return [r[0] + r[2]];
          break;
        case 2:
          return [r[0] * r[2]];
          break;
        case 3:
           return [r[0]/r[2]];
           break;  
      }
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2,4,r.length).setValues(r);
}
```

| Operand1 | Operation | Operand2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | - | 74 | -73 |
| 17 | / | 66 | 0.2575757576 |
| 14 | + | 89 | 103 |
| 76 | + | 2 | 78 |
| 72 | / | 27 | 2.666666667 |
| 42 | + | 85 | 127 |
| 34 | * | 62 | 2108 |
| 50 | + | 80 | 130 |
| 33 | - | 40 | -7 |
| 61 | * | 34 | 2074 |
| 30 | / | 66 | 0.4545454545 |
| 98 | / | 69 | 1.420289855 |
| 27 | - | 26 | 1 |
| 74 | - | 15 | 59 |
| 44 | * | 14 | 616 |
| 66 | - | 42 | 24 |
| 43 | / | 64 | 0.671875 |
| 96 | - | 83 | 13 |
| 52 | - | 29 | 23 |
| 17 | + | 77 | 94 |
| 30 | + | 34 | 64 |
| 31 | / | 31 | 1 |
| 26 | + | 67 | 93 |
| 53 | + | 68 | 121 |